# Is there any way of fixing this Visual studio 2015 Nuget Pacage Manager mess?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

It seems I managed to completely break my Visual Studio 2015 setup by uninstalling Nuget Package Manager. I uninstalled it in order to fix its inability to update anything. Now, when I try to launch VS I get a plethora of error messages, but the most important one seems to be shown on the image below as its showing no matter what fix I attempt:

[image: Error message shown on launch]

Here are the steps I took before I started seeing the above error:

1. I have renamed the Extensions folder found at the following path:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and installed Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015 from the microsoft website.
2. New extensions folder was created and when I tried to run the application with nothing else in it I would get the error message above once on VS launch and once on project load. When I moved old package folders from the old extensions folder I would get a lot more error messages related to the packages.

I also noticed there is an Extensions folder found at %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0, but renaming the folder to something else and just having blank folder did not help either. Also, I saw somewhere else a possible fix to an issue I thought was similar by removing contents of the folder located at: %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache, but that didn't help either. Now with all this trying I am getting to a point where fresh install might be an only option.

UPDATE:
I guess I managed to overcome this issue by opening up this project in Visual Studio 2017. It worked without any issues, though when I originally cloned the repository from GitHub via Visual Studio 2017 it didn't work. Having said all that, I don't think its an answer I was looking for, but at least I can continue working on this project.

Comment: You can try to repair vs2015. Go to Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a program find vs2015 right-click and choose change then you can repair it. Or you can try to reinstall it.

Comment: If none of these work, you can create an issue in DC. I give you the [entry for .NET](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=61&entry=problem) as reporting VS related issues needs to have VS Installer or higher versions of VS like VS 2017 installed. But don't worry, the thread will be triaged to VS Product Team with the correct vs setup tag.